# prints out answer more than once Java

Tags: java

Hi I have implemented a program which is supposed to search for a number in an array by searching in the middle of two numbers. It works, however, it prints out what key it has in the array multiple times?

here is my code;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sokning_exkod_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] minarray = new int[100];
        int antalelement = minarray.length;

        for (int i = 0; i<antalelement; i++) {
            minarray[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100)+1;
        }

        Arrays.sort(minarray);

        for (int i = 0; i<antalelement; i++) {
            if (i%25 == 0 && i != 0){
                System.out.println("| ");
            }
            System.out.print(minarray[i] + " ");
        }

        for(int i=0; i < antalelement; i++){
            if(minarray[i] == 73){
                hittaTalet(minarray);
                break;
            }
            else if(i == antalelement-1){
                System.out.println("Talet 73 finns inte i arrayen");
            }
        }
    }

    static void hittaTalet (int[] minarray){
        int y = minarray.length-1;
        int x = minarray.length/2;
        int soktaTal = 0;

        sokTal(minarray, y, x, soktaTal);
    }

    static void sokTal(int[] minarray, int y, int x, int soktaTal){
        int y2;
        boolean hittat = false;
        while(x < y || hittat == false){
            if(minarray[x] == 73){
                soktaTal++;
                hittat = true;
                break;
            }

            else if(minarray[x] > 73){
                soktaTal++;
                y2 = x;
                x = mittenHigh(y, x);
                y = y2;
                sokTal(minarray, y, x, soktaTal);
            }

            else if(minarray[x] < 73){
                soktaTal++;
                x = mittenLow(y, x);
                sokTal(minarray, y, x, soktaTal);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Talet 73 var på plats " + x + " och det tog " + soktaTal + " sökningar"); /* this part is only supposed to print out once */
    }

    static int mittenLow(int y, int x){
        return x+((y-x)/2);
    }

    static int mittenHigh(int y, int x){
        return x-((y-x)/2);
    }
}
```

example on an output:

```
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 5 5 | 
5 6 6 7 7 8 10 12 13 13 | 
14 15 15 17 18 18 21 22 22 22 | 
23 26 27 29 31 31 31 32 33 34 | 
37 38 39 39 39 39 41 43 43 44 | 
45 45 47 47 48 49 52 54 55 56 | 
59 59 64 64 65 65 66 68 69 71 | 
71 73 74 74 80 80 81 81 82 82 | 
83 84 85 85 85 86 87 87 87 88 | 
90 90 90 90 94 96 96 99 99 99 x är 50 +  y är 99
x är 74 +  y är 99
x är 62 +  y är 74
x är 68 +  y är 74
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar // <- this should only be printed once
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
x är 68 +  y är 74
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
x är 62 +  y är 74
x är 68 +  y är 74
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
x är 68 +  y är 74
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
x är 74 +  y är 99
x är 62 +  y är 74
x är 68 +  y är 74
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
x är 68 +  y är 74
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
x är 62 +  y är 74
x är 68 +  y är 74
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
x är 68 +  y är 74
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
Talet 73 var på plats 71 och det tog 5 sökningar
```

I'm not good with codes, just reading my first java course in school. And also, someone mentioned a debugger? What is that?

Comment: Ah.. my eyes .. :(. Debugger is your friend.

Comment: Specify which answer is printed twice. Post some output.

Comment: And please, when you submit a question to SO, try to write it in english.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 times `else if (minarray[x] > 73)`. I guess one of them should not be that but the opposite check `else if (minarray[x] < 73)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(minarray[x] > 73){
            soktaTal++;
            System.out.println("x är " + x + " + " + " y är " + y);
            y2 = x;
            x = mittenHigh(y, x);
            y = y2;
            sokTal(minarray, y, x, soktaTal);
        }

        else if(minarray[x] < 73)
```

It's already that? One is else if(minarray[x] < 73) and one is else if(minarray[x] > 73).

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear from first view that the problem has got something to do with the static  definition of method soktaTal() and hittaTalet().Please try and rectify it.

And coming to the debugger.It is a computer program that is used to test and debug other programs .It helps in analyzing how the control flows in your programme.